# How to click programmatically a child component? react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, the parent and child. Currently I have these codes below. But unfortunately it returns an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

For some reasons I want when button is click the Item component also will be click. But these codes below produces an error above. Anyone does know how to achieve it?
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

```
const App = (props) => {
  const itemRef = useRef(null);
  
  return (
    <div>
    {dynamicBoolean ? (
         <button onClick={() => itemRef.current.click()}>
            click item
        </button>
    ) : (
        //more codes here
        <Item ref={itemRef} />
    )}  
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Child component** would look like below (demonstration purposes, the code is very lengthly)

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
        //some design here
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: You forget to use `useRef`. That should be the trick. Functional components handle that differently than class components. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-function-components

Comment: @Felix sorry forgot to put in the codes. now updated.

Comment: Can you show the `Item` componet?

Comment: `Item` will need to use `forwardRef` to forward the ref to the DOM element

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar included the child in the description :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `useRef` and you have to forward this ref to the Item component.

```
import React, { forwardRef, useRef } from 'react';

const Item = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <li {...props}
  onClick={() => alert('clicked on Item')}
  ref={ref} >MyItem</li>
})

const App = (props) => {
  const itemRef = useRef(null);
  
  return (
    <div>
     <button onClick={() => itemRef.current.click()}>
        click item
    </button>
     
     
      <Item ref={itemRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I think this would solve my problem sir, but can't verify. Because current implementation is using conditional (see updated description), causing it to still display the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";

const Hello = (props) => {
  const itemRef = createRef();
  const hello = () => {
    itemRef.current.click();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => hello()}>click item</button>
      <Item ref={itemRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Item = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const myClick = () => {
    console.log("this is clicked");
  };
  return (
    <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton" onClick={myClick}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
});

export default Hello;
```

Comment: You can use createRef , and then click that element as shown above. Cheers!