# How to use preventDefault function in useRef (reactjs + nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

This is my function to download zip file
autoDownload.current.click() - automatically click on HTML element which download my zip file.
But Problem is page used to reload while this process.
How i can prevent my page to reload.

```
const downloadZipFile = () => { 
    console.log('download');
    autoDownload.current.click();
}
```

I need something like this.

```
const downloadZipFile = () => { 
    console.log('download');
    autoDownload.current.click((e) => {
      e.preventDefalut();
    });
}
```

Comment: You can try wrapping the component being clicked with a forwardRef and providing the click handler. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66883184/13023138

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an 'onClick' property to the link/button with a function that includes the `e.preventDefault()` ?  Not sure exactly how you're setting this up, but below has some ideas (using reactjs).

```js
const downloadZipFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Add your download zip functionality here
}

// Example of function that will execute on page load
React.useEffect(() => {
    downloadZipFile()
}, [])

return (
    <Button id='someid' onClick={downloadZipFile} />
)
```